# Declare function with undefined type

Tags: ada

I want to create a library taking a kind of generic type (or something like this, I don't know how it is called).

What I have :

```
package A is
    type A_Type is record
        Field : Field_Type;
        A_Access : access A;
    end record;
end A;

package B is
    type B_Type is record
        OtherField : OtherField_Type;
        B_Access : access B;
    end record;
end B;
```

I want to create a common library taking A_Type or B_Type as parameters. My library cannot include A or B. It will be something like :

```
package CommonLib is
    procedure DoStuff (Param : Generic_Type);
end CommonLib;

-- Can be used by A :
A : A_Type;
CommonLib.DoStuff(A);

-- Can be used by B :
B : B_Type;
CommonLib.DoStuff(B);
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Why don't you use a generic package ? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics

Comment: More [here](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/generics.html#generics).

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it a couple of different ways.  You can make a "generic" procedure (or a generic package with a procedure).  Or you can create an interface type that you can make custom types of.  Each has different pros and cons depending on how you want to use the code.

```ada
procedure Example is
    
    -- Generic method where you provide the type
    generic
        type Element_Type(<>) is limited private;
    procedure Do_Something(Value : Element_Type);

    procedure Do_Something(Value : Element_Type) is
    begin
        null;
    end Do_Something;

    procedure Do_Something_A is new Do_Something(Integer);
    procedure Do_Something_B is new Do_Something(String);


    -- Interface method where you can make custom types that provide their own implementations
    package Common_Lib is
        type Element_Interface is limited interface;
        procedure Do_Something(Value : Element_Interface) is abstract;
    end Common_Lib;

    type My_Type_A is new Common_Lib.Element_Interface with record
        Value : Integer := 10;
    end record;

    procedure Do_Something(Value : My_Type_A) is
    begin
        null;
    end Do_Something;

    type My_Type_B is new Common_Lib.Element_Interface with record
        Value : String(1..5) := "Hello";
    end record;

    procedure Do_Something(Value : My_Type_B) is
    begin
        null;
    end Do_Something;

    v1 : Integer := 10;
    v2 : String := "Hello";
    v3 : My_Type_A;
    v4 : My_Type_B;
begin
    Do_Something_A(v1);
    Do_Something_B(v2);
    v3.Do_Something;
    v4.Do_Something;
end Example;
```

Comment: Hard to know what the generic version of `Do_Something` could actually _do_. Wouldn’t you have to provide a formal procedure to do the something? in which case, what’s the point?

Comment: @SimonWright Yep.  I was just working with what the OP gave me.  With a more detailed question, I could have added some more tailored examples.  And by the looks of their supplied answer, whatever they are doing doesn't seem to need the extra?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for generic and this is what I've done :

```
generic
    type X_type is private;
package CommonLib is
    procedure DoStuff (Param : X_Type);
end CommonLib;

-- Used like this in A :
package A is
    type A_Type is record
        Field : Field_Type;
        A_Access : access A;
    end record;
    package CommonLibA is new CommonLib(A_Type);

    -- Now I can use CommonLibA.DoStuff(A)
end A;
```

I don't know if it is the best way but it seems to work.